# Checking $X \to S[J^{-1}] \wedge X$ is an $S[J^{-1}]$ equivalence.

Tags: stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

This is surely a trivial question, since all sources seem to relegate it to an exercise. Here's my attempt at a proof. Is this the idea? Please excuse the wordiness of the exposition, it's from my own little collection of proofs I tex up along the way.

Let $J \subset \mathbb Z$ be a set of primes. Consider the spectrum
\begin{equation*}
 S[J^{-1}] = \mathrm{hocolim}\left(S \xrightarrow{j_1} S  \xrightarrow{j_1j_2} S  \xrightarrow{j_1j_2j_3} \cdots\right).
 \end{equation*}

Since smash commutes with homotopy colimits (not sure if it does in general, but I'm pretty sure what we observe below is true) we get for any spectrum $X$
\begin{align*}
 \pi_*(S[J^{-1}] \wedge X) &= \pi_*\left( \mathrm{hocolim}\left(S \wedge X \xrightarrow{j_1} S \wedge X \xrightarrow{j_1j_2} S \wedge X \xrightarrow{j_1j_2j_3} \cdots\right) \right)\\ 
 &\cong \mathrm{colim} \,\pi_\ast(X \wedge S)\\ 
 &\cong \pi_*(X)[J^{-1}]  \\
 &\cong \pi_*(S)[J^{-1}] \otimes_{\pi_*(S)} \pi_*(X)
\end{align*}

In what follows, we tensor over $\pi_*(S)$. We show that $X = S \wedge X \to S[J^{-1}] \wedge X$ induced by the obvious map on the first factors is an $S[J^{-1}]$ equivalence.

We consider the map
\begin{equation}
S[J^{-1}] \wedge S \wedge X \to S[J^{-1}] \wedge S[J^{-1}] \wedge X.
\end{equation}
Upon taking $\pi_\ast$, this can be identified with the map (do what we did above twice!)
\begin{equation}
\pi_\ast(S) \otimes \pi_*(X)[J^{-1}] \to \pi_\ast(S)[J^{-1}] \otimes \pi_*(X)[J^{-1}]
\end{equation}
given by $a \otimes b \mapsto a \otimes b$. This can further be identified with
\begin{equation}
 \pi_*(X)[J^{-1}] \to \pi_\ast(S)[J^{-1}] \otimes \pi_*(X)[J^{-1}]
\end{equation}
via $b \mapsto 1 \otimes b$
which is an isomorphism since we have no $J$-torsion on both sides (In a low brow fashion, one can write out elementary tensors, adding factors of $\frac{j_i}{j_i}$ if necessary)

A remark: This is akin to the algebraic fact that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]
\end{equation}
induces an isomorphism
\begin{equation}
A \to \mathbb Z[J^{-1}]\otimes_{\mathbb Z} A
\end{equation}
if $A$ has no $J$-torsion.

Comment: You can simplify the proof by reducing to the case $X = S$, and also it is possible to argue without passing to the homotopy groups.